# Wygwam not showing or loading in Channel Entry

Tags: matrix, wygwam

Upgraded our EE install to 2.8.1, installed Matrix plugin and also upgraded an older version from Wygwam to the latest version, but Wygwam isn't showing in the Matrix publish field. Any ideas or thoughts where to look?

Comment: Does the version of Wygwam you updated to show in the list of installed modules in CP > Add Ons > Modules?

Can you select a Wygwam field outside of a matrix field, and does this work in the channel publish page?

There's not a lot to go on from your post, but we've not seen any conflict with Wygwam and EE 2.8.1.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Wygwam does not load in the Channel Entry page. Wygwam v 3.3.1 and EE 2.8.1. I have deleted all Wygwam folders and re-uploaded again. The Wygwam version does show in the Add-Ons > Modules as installed. Side note: My wygwam download from devotEE seems to have a hidden file duplicate for every file and directory also. They all start with "._filname" or "._directory". is that normal??

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleared your browser cache, database cache and refreshed? Wygwam is very sensitive to this.